# What is a concise word or phrasing for "in a context without a user"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a concise word or phrasing for "in a context without a user"?  This is obviously in the context of software.  More generally, what is a concise way of saying, "in a context without X (where X is usually assumed)?"

Comment: Since X is *usually* assumed in whatever context you're looking to talk about in a context where X is specifically *not* present, I think it would be a mistake to look for a really concise way of making that point. You'd probably be better off explaining *why* X isn't involved, since that's what makes your context **atypical** (perhaps **pathological**, if you want to sound really erudite).

Comment: Isn't that just a "batch job"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Over the years I've written various programs that originally were intended to be explicitly run by an actual human user, who would interact with the program to perform some task.

At some later time it may be useful to run such a program from a 'batch' file. Perhaps run at some configured 'slack' time when there is no user present, perhaps with a command-line option to specify exactly which task to perform, and how.

In such circumstances the program needs to know which 'mode' it's running in. For example, you can't just display an error message and wait for the user to select *Cancel/Continue* if there's nobody around to read it and respond.

My programs normally used a boolean flag **unattended**, set *true* if there was no user available to control progress (in which case the programs would perform some sensible default action as required).

Comment: I liked "autonomous" too ( @aedia ), but I think "unattended" is probably the better choice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, You don't use Stackoverflow?

Comment: @Pacerier: I don't see the relevance, since I was using my variable name decades before SO existed. But I assume you can see from my network profile that in 4 years I've asked 2 questions and posted 3 answers on Stackoverflow. Neither question got a "satisfactory" answer, and the answers were either ignored or downvoted. I suppose I'd have to say I don't really "use" it, since apparently neither of us are any use to the other.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I saw your profile which states you're a coder? So what do you mean by "neither of us are any use to the other"?

Comment: @Pacerier: Oops - just realized the potential ambiguity there! I didn't mean *you* and I are no use to each other (perish the thought! :). I meant I get no benefit from ***Stackoverflow***, and vice-versa.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, But coders use Stackoverflow like *daily*, or have you retired from coding already.

Comment: @Pacerier: That's a moot point! I'm certainly not likely to ever get *paid* to write code again, having last billed a customer nearly 6 years ago. But I wrote [a text-to-speech plugin for the Foobar audio player](http://www.hydrogenaud.io/forums/index.php?showtopic=85308&hl=foo_tts) in the early days of my (enforced, not chosen) idleness. I was a bit surprised/disappointed to find that hardly anyone on the Net seemed to be interested - but I used it myself on a daily basis for years, and it's always impressed visitors to my house...

Comment: ...until I switched from XP to Win7 a few months ago, since which the plugin doesn't work. I used a "pre-programmed config screen" built into the Foobar shell, but that either no longer exists or isn't called in the same way as it was before, so it doesn't display. Under Win7 my default "volume of speech relative to music playback" is almost inaudibly low, but without access to the config screen I can't increase it. I keep telling myself I'll install MSVS on my current h/w and fix this, but without a nagging user base, I just never seem to get around to doing it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Nice, but being a linguistics major, how did you get acquainted with code in the first place?

Comment: @Pacerier: I only studied "English & French Language & Literatue with Linguistics" back in the early 70s because it was a 4-year course (with one year at a uni in France). Most degrees were 3 years, but I didn't fancy that because I had no idea what I might do *after*, so I figured I was "buying time". Then I worked on a building site for 18 months to pay off my student debts, and took a "temporary" Civil Service office job just to avoid being out on site for a second winter. As luck would have it, they trained me in computers (not a degree subject at the time). I took to it, so I kept it up.

Answer (score 5):

In a software context we sometimes talk about running "headless" clients, as an alternative to running GUIs.  I don't have a term that works in a non-software context.

Comment: Note that if you're running [headless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_system) you don't have a monitor but you could still have remote user input. The only other term I can think of is _autonomous_, also usually software- or at least machine-related.

Comment: @aedia:No. You are confusing two different meanings of "headless".

Comment: @Marcin: No need to be so negative - both meanings of *headless* are common in computing, and it is highly useful for someone thinking of using the term to be aware of both, so that they can avoid potential confusion :)

Comment: @Marcin "headless client" usage does seem to be closer to meaning a _daemon_,  software that runs autonomously/without a user. However, I think you could argue it includes the notion of running headlessly, that is, no GUI or front-end, so I'm not sure these are totally separate meanings. Perhaps in specific phrases there are technical differences - headless service, headless server, etc. :)

Comment: @aedia: A daemon runs independently of a user session, which is quite different from merely running headlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Another term is "interactive" and "non-interactive".

This can be used for example to describe ["logon types"](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/misc_network_security/Logon-Types.html#body).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest daemon mode or process.